# ¿Cómo validar la existencia de un dato en un DataGridView para evitar redundancia?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, condiciones, datagrid

Tengo un DataGridView que recibe datos de otro Grid que contiene productos para realizar un detalle de préstamos, sin embargo, cuando agrego datos al Grid de detalles, se puede agregar dos veces el mismo producto como si fuera uno nuevo. Por tal motivo, me gustaría saber de que manera puedo comprobar si ya existe el producto que estoy ingresanddo para evitar que se agregue nuevamente, el código que tengo es el siguiente.

```
string id_prod = frm_Buscar.id_producto;
            string nombre = frm_Buscar.nombre;
            string cant = frm_Buscar.cantidad;
            if (dtg_Detalle.RowCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtg_Detalle.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt16(dtg_Detalle.Rows[i].Cells["id_prod"].Value) == Convert.ToInt16(id_prod))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("El producto ya ha sido ingresado");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dtg_Detalle.Rows.Add(id_prod, nombre, cant);
                    }
                }                    
            }
            else
            {
                if(dtg_Detalle.RowCount == 0)
                {
                    dtg_Detalle.Rows.Add(id_prod, nombre, cant);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tienes algun problema con el codigo actual?

Comment: El problema es que se le agrega más de una vez el mismo registro.

Comment: El problema que presenta el código actual, es que si valida sí existe el id, sin embargo, al ser un ciclo for pasa al siguiente número y me agrega una nueva fila de todas maneras

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:  Pasar los Datos al nuevo Datagrid atravez de un forech, tomas el dato que vas a insertar, recorres el segundo datagrid evaluando que este dato no exista si existe lo omites sino pues procedes a realizar la inserción del mismo

Comment: ese es mi problema, realmente soy relativamente nuevo en la programación, y no estoy seguro de que manera pueda usar el foreach, sólo lo he utilizado para agregar datos a la base de datos, y no encuentro como adaptarlo para validar si existe el dato

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu ciclo `for`, hay 2 cosas que pasan, que debieran estar separadas: preguntar si el registro ya existe, e intentar agregarlo. Te recomiendo que separes las tareas. Vale decir, algo como:

```
 if (dtg_Detalle.RowCount > 0)
 {
      // Primero averigua si el registro existe:
      bool existe = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < dtg_Detalle.RowCount; i++)
      {
         if (Convert.ToInt16(dtg_Detalle.Rows[i].Cells["id_prod"].Value) == Convert.ToInt16(id_prod))
         {
             MessageBox.Show("El producto ya ha sido ingresado");
             existe = true;
             break; // debes salirte del ciclo si encuentras el registro, no es necesario seguir dentro
         }
      }

      // Luego, ya fuera del ciclo, solo si no existe, realizas la insercion:
      if (existe == false)
      {
         dtg_Detalle.Rows.Add(id_prod, nombre, cant);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Esto ha funcionado perfecto, te agradezco.